# Backbone Model ids not assigned to Model, nor is Collection url attribute assigned to Models. Models are aways considered new

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, frontend

My backbone Model:

```
  var Location = Backbone.Model.extend({

    idAttribute: "_id",

    // Default attributes ensure that each todo created has `title` and `completed` keys.
    defaults: {
      nick_name: null, //Example: The Office

      street_address: '214 West 29th Street',
      extended_address: null, // Example: Suite 205
      cross_street: null,
      locality: 'New York',
      region: 'NY',
      postal_code: 10001,
      country: 'United States',

    },

    initialize: function() {
    }

  });
```

My backbone collection:

```
  var LocationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // Reference to this collection's model.
    model: Location

  });
```

I have a global variable that is a JSON array of models:

```
json_data = [{country: "United States of America",
cross_street: "",
extended_address: "",
id: 3,
locality: "Brooklyn",
nick_name: "",
postal_code: 11208,
region: "NY",
street_address: "3039 Fulton street"}]
```

When i try to add the array of model attributes to the Collection the models are always treated as new Models not as saved to the database. Thus, I try to call save on any of the models and I get a POST request instead of a PUT request. Also, i've tried just create the Models with no Collection, using the model set method, and the id attribute is never set to the Model id even though I can call the model_instance.attributes method and I see that id is part of the output.

```
this.locationCollection = new LocationCollection();
      this.locationCollection.url = urlRoot;
      this.locationCollection.add(json_data);

      this.locationCollection.each(function(model, index, option) {
        console.log(model.id);
        console.log(model.urlRoot)
        console.log(model.url)
        console.log(model.attributes);
      }, this)
```

Output from console logging:

undefined 
undefined 
some function for url 
{country: "United States of America",
    cross_street: "",
    extended_address: "",
    id: 3,
    locality: "Brooklyn",
    nick_name: "",
    postal_code: 11208,
    region: "NY",
    street_address: "3039 Fulton street"} // correct expected output for model.attributes

Please tell me if I'm adding models to a collection correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this definitely has to do with the `idAttribute` property you have set in your `Location` model. You have `id` as `3` in you `json_data` but you have set `idAttribute` to `_id`, so what might be happening is, since `json_data` doesn't have `_id` it is `undefined` and it is then set to your model's `id` so model's `id` becomes `undefined`. Now, since `id` is `undefined` on saving model, it will treat it as a new model and make a `POST` request.

From the [doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute):

> **idAttribute** model.idAttribute
>
> A model's unique identifier is stored under the id attribute. If
>   you're directly communicating with a backend (CouchDB, MongoDB) that
>   uses a different unique key, ***you may set a Model's idAttribute to***
>   ***transparently map from that key to id***.

**FIX:**

Either you remove the `idAttribute` you have set to `_id` or add a property `_id` to your `json_data`.